# Langchain DynamoDBChatMessageHistory add sortkey and customer attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, langchain

A conversational chain with DynamoDb for memory is setup.
Everything works fine, regarding retrieving and inserting messages into the memory. However, I want to add a sortkey and add custom attributes on top of the base key provided by the `DynamoDBChatMessageHistory` class.

```
    const { DynamoDBChatMessageHistory } = require("@langchain/community/stores/message/dynamodb");

    const MESSAGE_HISTORY = new DynamoDBChatMessageHistory(
      {
        tableName: "Conversation",
        partitionKey: "studentId", // documentation requires this to be unique, 
                                   // however i want to partition using the studentId
        studentId: studentId.toString(),
        sortKey: "sessionId", // i want to add this sortkey
        sessionId: `chat_${sessionId}`, // this is not applied
        dateTimeStamp: new Date(), // i want to add this custom attribute
        config: {
          region: "us-east-1",
          credentials: {
            accessKeyId: process.env.ACCESS_KEY_ID,
            secretAccessKey: process.env.SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
          },
        },
      }
    )
```

DynamoDb:

[image: Dynamo]

I realize this is incorrect in terms of dynamo conventions, I need support on how to extend the base `DynamoDBChatMessageHistory` to suit my requirements.

Answer (score -1):

Its very well explained in the documentation:

#### Composite Keys

When using an existing DynamoDB table, you may need to modify the key structure from the default of to something including a Sort Key. To do this you may use the key parameter.

Passing a value for key will override the primary_key parameter, and the resulting key structure will be the passed value.

```
from langchain_community.chat_message_histories import DynamoDBChatMessageHistory

composite_table = dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName="CompositeTable",
    KeySchema=[
        {"AttributeName": "studentId", "KeyType": "HASH"},
        {"AttributeName": "sessionId", "KeyType": "RANGE"},
    ],
    AttributeDefinitions=[
        {"AttributeName": "PK", "AttributeType": "S"},
        {"AttributeName": "SK", "AttributeType": "S"},
    ],
    BillingMode="PAY_PER_REQUEST",
)

# Wait until the table exists.
composite_table.meta.client.get_waiter("table_exists").wait(TableName="CompositeTable")

# Print out some data about the table.
print(composite_table.item_count)
```

[src](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/memory/aws_dynamodb)

You cannot alter keys on an existing table, you must always create a new table.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. My dynamo setup is as you have mentioned. This is a problem with langchain's class. where it does not allow me to set a sortKey and custom attributes. Im looking for a workaround for this.

Comment: Your looking for a workaround for a problem that does not exist. You do not define non-key attributes in DynamoDB. LangChain connector is simply abstracting the DynamoDB API and is why you only define keys. Non key attributes can be added to you items payload at will.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand that the LangChain connector abstracts the DynamoDB API and allows for the addition of non-key attributes independently. However, I'm still encountering difficulties when trying to populate the sort key ("sessionId") using the connector. Could you please provide more detailed guidance on how to ensure that the sort key is correctly populated in the DynamoDB table when using the LangChain connector for insertion? Any additional insights or workaround suggestions would be greatly appreciated